# How can I log SSL protocol on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

Nginx can do that with `$ssl_protocol`.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables

Is something like this possible with Apache?

Comment: Yes. Read the docs at http://httpd.apache.org

Answer (score 2):

Add `%{SSL_PROTOCOL}x` to your log format ([doc link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html)).